# How to keep variable as a collection

Tags: laravel

I try to keep my variable as a collection while sending my form. This collection is being transformed into a string but I absolutely need to keep it as a collection to call my different relationships.

My controller:

```
public function filter(Request $request)
    {

        $searchResult = collect(json_decode($request->searchresult));

        return view('customers.pages.home.filter', compact('searchResult'));
    }
```

Currently, I transform my result into an array and then into a Collection but I find myself very quickly limited to call my relationships (non functional)

I submit my form like this:

```
<form action="{{ url('/search/filter') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input class="form-control" name="searchresult" type="hidden" value="{{ $searchResult }}">
     <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="button" type="submit">Apply</button>
</form>
```

Actual result of `$request->searchresult`:

[image: actual result]

Expected result: Collection

[image: expected result]

(As in my function search()):

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $searchResult = Product::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')->get();
        $searchResult = $searchResult->where('published', 0);

        dd($searchResult);


        return view('customers.pages.home.search', compact('searchResult'));
    }
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? its a bit unclear. how does $request->searchResult look like?

Comment: I just edited my question for actual result and expected result

Comment: added an answer. can you check whether it works the way you expect and let us know :)

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here

return view('customers.pages.home.filter', ['searchResult' => searchResult]);
```

will send a collection variable `$searchResult`.

Comment: I want to pass my collection from the search() function to my view, then redistribute this same collection with my form in the filter() function. Your code doesn't work because this variable is already not sent correctly with $request->searchresult which returns a string

Comment: i would recommend you pass just the ids. because you cant send the request data in the form of collection. what you can do is pass the collection to search and then send the ids of the models to filter. when you receive the ids to filter method better do a whereIn query again.